# Нужны ли тире?

Tags: тире

В Минске я хочу увидеть здание Национальной библиотеки, в Харькове - площадь Свободы, в Будапеште - Парламент.

Comment: @Nataly Barsa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставила. Тут тире заменяет оборот "хочу увидеть", поэтому вполне к месту.

Answer (score 1):

Да, тире нужно. Оно заменяет упомянутый ранее оборот "хочу увидеть". Это т.н. эллиптические предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Тире нужны, так как заменяют пропущенные слова, которые легко восстанавливается из текста

Answer (score 0):

И я бы поставил.  Если бы пауза была.  Паузы нет - тире нет.